# .load() jquery slow when include script like javascript or css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code:
First.html
..

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/prj1100.js"></script>
 <LINK href="../css/prj1100.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
..
```

Event to load page.html

```
  jQuery(".content").click(function(){
 $(".content_2").load('page.html');}
```

Inside page.html, there are:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/prj1100.js"></script>
 <LINK href="../css/prj1100.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <?php

 ...
```

This code works perfectly however when click more than one time to load this page is taking too much time to show page.html. Its seems that .load() instance every time .js into memory.

I included  on page.html again because  declared on first.html not inherited to page.html.

How can I improve this code ?

Comment: Don't  you experience `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, we wont have to link jquery libraries and other files in both pages repeatedly.
Libraries and stylesheets linked to first.html must work for page.html as well. See this link [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/F4p2lap4cNQyqf2HYqWK?p=preview)

index.html

```
<h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
<button>Load First</button>
<div class="first"></div>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    alert('index loaded!');
    $('button').click(function() {
      $('.first').load('first.html');
    })
  });
</script>
```

first.html

```
<h1>Hello First!</h1>  

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    alert('first loaded!');
  });
</script>
```

However, if you still have to link all the files and scripts in both the pages, the most efficient way to do it is at the bottom of your pages. DOM load time is significantly shortened.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can not post comment, so I have to ask my question as an answer, do you want to load `html content` with `ajax`?
If so, you need to apply some changes to your code, first you should add a `class` or `id` to target content, like this:

```
<body>
    <div class='target'>
        // ....
    </div>
</body>
```

then you should load only `target`, like this:

```
$('#result').load( URL + " .target" );
```

You can use `[pjax]` too. (https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax)

I hope I got you correctly and this help to you.